# Kubuntu screenshot opens KSnapshot rather than saving to file

Tags: kubuntu, ksnapshot

In Kubuntu (14.04) the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> key opens KSnapshot, a graphical program for choosing how to save the screenshot. When taking lots of screenshots it is more convenient for screenshots to save automatically to a timestamped file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PrintScreen From Terminal**

From the terminal we can produce the screenshots we want with the ImageMagik `import` command. To save a time-stamped full-screen screenshot to your pictures folder run:

```
import -window root ~/Pictures/screenshot$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S").png
```

To save a time-stamped screenshot of the current window to your pictures folder run:

```
import -window $(xdotool getwindowfocus) ~/Pictures/screenshot$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S").png
```

(This may require you to install `xdotool` with `sudo apt-get install xdotool` if it is not already installed.)

**Setting up the hotkeys**

If this commands work then you can assign the hotkeys by opening system settings and selecting "Shortcuts and Gestures"

[image: Shortcut settings]

Select "Custom Shortcuts". At the bottom of the list select "Edit">"New">"Global Shortcut">"Command/URL". Rename the shortcut and select the "Trigger" tab. Click The button labelled "None" and then press the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> key. This will warn you you are reassigning this away from PrintScreen, click "reassign".

[image: SetUpKey]

Now select the "Action" tab and enter `import -window root ~/Pictures/screenshot$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S").png`. And click "Apply" at the bottom of the screen.

[image: SetUpCommand]

Repeat this process with your chosen shortcut for the print window command (`import -window $(xdotool getwindowfocus) ~/Pictures/screenshot$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S").png`) if desired.

Finally select "Global Keyboard Shortcuts" from the left. And "khotkeys" from the dropdown. Your new shortcuts should be listed. As is "PrintScreen" the launcher for KSnapshot. If desired click "PrintScreen" and click the "None" button to reassign it to a new shortcut.

[image: FinalSettings]